# Importing data from a single line

Tags: import

So I have a textfile looking like this:

```
0.15 0.2 10 0 0 0 0.2 0.5 0.1 0.01 100000 1000000 100000
```

Now I want to Import the third entry of the line.
I have tried it like this:

```
Import[".../Desktop/data.txt", {"Data", {3}}]
```

But I got this error `"The Import element "3" is not present when importing as Text.

Comment: You can also just do `Import[file, "Table"][[1, 3]]` (or some minor variant on that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have only reals numbers separated by spaces:

```
ToExpression@TextWords[Import["input.txt"]][[3]]

(* 10 *)
```

does the job.

Comment: More efficient would just be a `StringSplit[line, " ", 4][[3]]`

Comment: Why "more efficient"? and, the OP maybe needs the number and not the string...

Comment: I was assuming you'd just use the `ToExpression` again. Performance wise comparing `ToExpression@TextWords[line][[3]] // RepeatedTiming // First` and `ToExpression@StringSplit[line, " ", 4][[3]] // RepeatedTiming // First` there's over an order of magnitude gain.

Comment: Even more efficient `ToExpression@StringSplit[Import["input.txt"]][[3]]` ... ;))

Answer (score 2):

You can use streams:

```
stream = OpenRead["text.txt"];
Skip[stream, Number, 2];
Read[stream, Number]
Close[stream];
```

> 10

I'm not sure how fast it is, I have only  used it for binary files where instead of `Skip` one can use `SetStreamPosition` which is very fast.

Comment: You can do this with a single `ReadList`, too. i.e. `ReadList[file, Number, 3][[3]]`. And `ReadList` will auto-open and auto-close, cutting out that part of the code.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Yes but then mathematica won't understand that the first `n-1` entries should be discarded immidiately. A list will be constructed just to take a single element

Comment: True, but that will only really matter at very, very large values of `n`.